# How export a function with functions inside?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a 'class' with function. I know a way to do it using object, like:

```
var x = {
    test: function(){
        console.log("worked");
    }
}
```

And I saw a Example using:

```
var x = function () {
    var test = function () {
        console.log("worked")
    }
    return {x:x};
}
```

But with that last example, I will need return every function that I create... It's useless...

Is there another way to acess functions inside functions? Without use class or object? Just Functions.

Comment: I don’t think this is possible... Classes sounds like the "container" your are looking for. Is this for the browser of Node?

Comment: Why are you need it?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here. No, you can't create an object containing functions without using objects.

Comment: hm, I was just looking for alternatives for Classes and Objects. I heard around that `Classes` will be discontinued and we will use only functions. I'm new with javascript, so, sorry for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
exports.maker = function(){
 return function(){
    console.log('foo');
  }
}
```

or like this:

```
exports.maker = function(){
 return  {
   foo: function(){
    console.log('foo');
   }
 }
}
```

typically, people don't put class definitions inside functions:

```
exports.maker = function(){
 return  class Foo { ... }
}
```

but you can do that too. The reason why it's not typical to do that - every call to maker() is a different class, not the same and it's not as performant to do nest the class like.

Answer (score 0):

U can multi function export for example

```
function bar() {

}

function foo() {

}

module.exports = {
  foo,
  bar
};
```